# nodelets running with remote roscore are dying (bond broken)

Tags: ros, remote-roscore, nodelets, nodelet

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all (or, at least, the usual one who answers to my questions ;-)),
I have the following situation:

- LAPTOP1: **roscore**, roslaunch with **openni_node** and some **tf**
- LAPTOP2: roslaunch with some **depth_image_proc** nodelets, connected via ROS_MASTER_URI=http://LAPTOP1

the problem is that the nodelets on LAPTOP2 are alive only for a short while (some seconds), then, they start to die, one after the other:

```
[ INFO] [1396535717.713638183]: Bond broken, exiting
[camera/register_depth_rgb-3] process has finished cleanly
```

What's going on? How can I run this configuration properly?
Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/148036/nodelets-running-with-remote-roscore-are-dying-(bond-broken)/) by [madmage](https://answers.ros.org/users/11946/madmage/) on ROS Answers with karma: 293 on 2014-04-03

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [madmage](https://answers.ros.org/users/11946/madmage/) on 2014-04-03**:
I tested also what happens without the **openni_node** on LAPTOP1 (i.e., there is no input for the nodelets on LAPTOP2, so they should not run, since their subscribed topics are not published): same behavior

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-04-03**:
What happens when you start the roscore on laptop2 instead?

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-04-03**:
Moreover, do other nodes / nodelets have the same problems on laptop2, or is it just the image_proc nodelets?

**Comment by [madmage](https://answers.ros.org/users/11946/madmage/) on 2014-04-03**:
I can run the nodelets on laptop2 with a roscore on laptop2, everything works (this is actually how everything has begun).
Can you tell me a simple nodelet I can test (to see if it's a depth_image_proc problem or nodelet problem)?

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-04-03**:
Have you tried simple nodes on laptop2 with core on laptop1? Something like `rostopic pub` or `rostopic sub`?

**Comment by [madmage](https://answers.ros.org/users/11946/madmage/) on 2014-04-03**:
The openni_node running on laptop1 publishes /camera/rgb/image_raw and /camera/depth/image_raw (roscore is on laptop1), I can see that image by subscribing it from laptop2 with rqt_image_view.

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-04-04**:
Ok. I don't know what could be the problem, sorry. @esteve, @tfoote, any idea how to investigate this best?

**Comment by [madmage](https://answers.ros.org/users/11946/madmage/) on 2014-04-04**:
I rewrote launch files, rebooted laptops, upgraded packages... now it works (more or less)... could it be that was because I had image_transport package installed on one laptop (LAPTOP1) and not the other?

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-04-04**:
Could. Don't really know, but it sounds strang that it ran at all if image_transform was not installed... Let us know if this continues to be a problem.

**Comment by [madmage](https://answers.ros.org/users/11946/madmage/) on 2014-04-04**:
However, it seems that now it is working. I am still confused about who (which nodelet) is subscribing what (what topic) and using *what*kind*of*compression* (how to know it?), since running nodes with _image_transport:=theora does not make much difference in network traffic monitors

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-04-04**:
I don't know enough about how image transport works to answer that. I probably makes sense to open a new question about it if you can't find anything in the docs or with google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So, summarizing, I just resolved by rebooting both machines, rewriting both launch files, installing missing image_transport plugins on LAPTOP2.

---

Originally posted by [madmage](https://answers.ros.org/users/11946/madmage/) with karma: 293 on 2014-04-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4